# Kivy create pulsing background

Tags: python, animation, kivy

I'm trying to create pulsing background in my app. Following this question [Pulsing Background Color in Kivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54598379/pulsing-background-color-in-kivy)

i've tried to make it work also, but for some reason it doesn't work. Here's my main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.clock import Clock

Window.size = (360,600)

class MyGridLayout(Screen):    
   def blink(self):
       x = Clock.schedule_once(self.start_pulsing,2)
       return x

   def start_pulsing(self,*args):
       anim = Animation(animated_color=(1,0,0,1))
       anim.start(self)
       anim.repeat = True


class mainApp(App):
  def build(self):
    return MyGridLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  mainApp().run()
```

And my main.kv file

```
<MyGridLayout>:
    FloatLayout:
        size: root.width, root.height
        animated_color:(1,1,1,1)
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba :self.animated_color
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
```

Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple problems with your code:

- The `animated_color` property in your `kv` is a property of the `FloatLayout`, but your python code references it as a property of `MyGridLayout`.
- The `anim.repeat = True` will cause the `Animation` to be repeated, but after the first animation, the `animated_color` is already `(1,0,0,1)`, so the repeated `Animation` will have no effect.
- I don't see any code calling the `blink()` method to actually start the pulsing.

Here is a modified version of your code that reflects the above changes:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ColorProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.clock import Clock

Window.size = (360,600)

class MyGridLayout(Screen):
   animated_color = ColorProperty()  # the color property to be animated
   pulse_interval = 4  # the interval for pulsing

   def blink(self):
       x = Clock.schedule_once(self.start_pulsing,2)
       return x

   def start_pulsing(self,*args):
       d = self.pulse_interval /2
       anim = Animation(animated_color=(1,0,0,1), duration=d) + \
              Animation(animated_color=(1,1,1,1), duration=d)
       anim.repeat = True
       anim.start(self)

class mainApp(App):
  def build(self):
    root = MyGridLayout()
    root.blink()  # star the pulsing
    return root

if __name__ == '__main__':
  mainApp().run()
```

And the modified `main.kv`:

```
<MyGridLayout>:
    FloatLayout:
        size: root.width, root.height
        # animated_color:(1,1,1,1)  # property needs to be attribute of MyGridLayout
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba :root.animated_color  # reference the animated_color property of MyGridLayout
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
```

Comment: Hi John, many thanks for your help. You seemed to be an expert at this. Could you tell me if its also possible to add an image, so it fades away when the pulse is at its peak?

Comment: You can animate the `opacity` of an `Image` widget. And you can use [parallel animations](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.animation.html#parallel-animation) to animatee it at the same time as the pulsing.